Horror Movie about woman trapped in a subway station
I watched this movie a long time ago when i was around 13 so i remember very few details about this movie. It probably came out between 2004-2010
and might be an european production.
Its about a woman who was abused as a child by a relative.
She talks to ominous people in the subway train who are having a party and  somehow  turn to lifeless corpses when the train stops.She might have been searching for something (sister?). I remember her getting stabbed and running away through a closed subway station. I think she has the ability to regenerate or is immortal?. Note that these events are only part of the movie (maybe 30 min ).
That's all I remember. I've tried hard to find this movie ever since, but no luck yet. Hope someone can help me remember the name!
@Richard thanks but its not End of the line

Could be Midnight Meat Train 2008 Starring a pre-hangover Bradley Cooper. But its a long shot

Could also be creep (2004), dont know much about the movie, so ican not say something about the scenes you describe, but its a horror movie about a woman trapped in a subway station

It was in a language other than english and they were being watched by the killer through thye subway security cams?

It sounds like Hellraiser: Deader. Main character (who was molested as a child) is tracking down the resurrection cult in a video and she gets on a train with a bunch of people who are dead but look alive when the train is moving. She is stabbed early on and keeps bleeding throughout the movie.
Edit: Now that I'm no longer at work: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337636/
The plot points aren't listed in the synopsis but they're there.

+1, this seems to fit the mentioned information and having watched it a couple of times over the years, it seems like a good call.

I don't remember much about the movie, but could be Creep (2004). Another user also pointed this movie as a guest. Follow a short description from imdb (my emphasis):

While inspecting the sewage system of London, two workers are attacked by a weird creature. Later, Kate decides to leave a party trying to meet the actor George Clooney who is in London. She waits for the last underground train, but after drinking many alcoholic beverages, she falls asleep accidentally on the platform bench, missing the last train and being trapped in the closed underground station. Later, a train going to the depot stops at the platform. She boards the train and she meets her acquaintance Guy, who tries to sexually assault her in the underground car. Guy is attacked by the creature, dragged off, and Kate leaves the train through the tunnel. This is the beginning of her claustrophobic, scary and gore night running through the Underground of London.

